# MediaEngine is unable to provide next frame with invalidates in the "background"

Tags: c#, winforms, directx, sharpdx

I have an application with two windows -- one is regular WinForms with live plot (which should be constantly updated) and the second window is DirectX/SharpDX with movie playing (MediaEngine).

In order to have live plot I call invalidate every 0.1 second and on paint even I redraw the plot. The problem is that after few seconds `MediaEngine` reports `false` for all `OnVideoStreamTick` calls meaning it does not have next frame to display.

If I comment out the drawing, ME is stuck as before but when I comment out invalidate calls (which as the effect causes redrawing) ME play backs movie with no problem.

What should I do to have live window and movie playing at the same time?

*Update, on the first lost frame I check the error and it says `DecodeError`. Also when I increase the plot update interval from 0.1s to 1s. the playback is OK for longer. Of course I am looking for something more solid than magically increasing the interval.*

Comment: Are you threading any of this?  If it's all piled onto the UI, then that's probably the issue.

Comment: @DonBoitnott, I tested it without any explicit thread/task, I also executed the second window (with player) in explicitly created new Task, and also in explicitly created thread. In all 3 cases the behavior is the same, ME reports no new frames.

Comment: Then if it's not a collision issue, I would have to guess that the way it's being fed the stream/data is getting lost.  Perhaps all of those redraws is simply causing enough of a delay that a receive timeout or something similar is occurring?

Comment: @DonBoitnott, you are right, thank you (I updated the question with new info). The question is how to make it reliable for good, if there is some time constraint for ME I would put it on separate task, but whole DX window is on separate task/thread.